# CalculateField with variables

Tags: python, arcpy, field-calculator, copy

I'm trying to make a python script on arcmap 10.2.2 which will copy values from an old field (selected by the user) and paste them in an new field (named by the user).
I wrote that:

```
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
layerforNewField =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
newfieldname =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
oldfield = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
calculate = "!oldfield!"

# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = fc

#add new field with "double type"
arcpy.AddField_management(layerforNewField, newfieldname, "DOUBLE", 10, 4)

#copy/paste values from a field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(layerforNewField, newfieldname, calculate, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Results: the new field is created, but the values didn't paste. The same script without variables is working. What's wrong? I think there is a problem on "calculate" variable, isn't it?

I have also tried:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(layerforNewField, newfieldname, '!' + calculate + '!', "PYTHON_9.3")
```

and:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(layerforNewField, newfieldname, """!{}!""".format(calculate), "PYTHON_9.3") with the same results
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you're correct in thinking there is a problem with the 'calculate' variable. i believe you would want something like

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(layerforNewField, newfieldname, '"!{}!"'.format(oldfield), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

otherwise, by setting

```
calculate = '!oldfield!'
```

the code is trying to insert values from the column 'oldfield', which i'm assuming doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much, you found my fault! Now I have a very different problem. The values moved but without decimals for example the value 69541,226563 moved as 695412265625. I used precision=25 and scale=4

Comment: would the oldfield be a text data type? Or something to do with region settings? perhaps arc sees the comma as a thousands separator rather than a decimal and removes it when transferring the value to a double field.

Comment: @apatera please post your comment as a new question

Comment: As the subject fits with my question, I think I should keep discuss the script here. Please correct me if I am wrong so that I will make a new post. I would like to be informed if I am able to copy values from a field type "Double" or "Integer" to a new field type "Double" or "float" with that script. In other words, I would like to know if I can change the type of a field. Now, I am trying to move values from a double to a float but the new field is double again. It is very weird.

Comment: additionally, comma is define correctly to be used as a decimal separator and dots are used as a thousands separator.